# What does it mean by latest appointment? Does it mean earliest or last?

Tags: word-usage

When someone says:

> 'What's the [latest](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/latest) appointment available today?'

Does it mean last appointment available today OR first available appointment today after time now?

I was under the impression that it means last available appointment but someone told me it means first available appointment after time now.

Comment: The latest appointment today.  For example, maybe the person will have to leave work or school early in order to get to the appointment.  By taking the latest slot available, they will be able to minimize the time lost from work or school.

Comment: In theory, it could also mean *What's the most recent appointment to have become available?* (It would normally only be used in that sense if somebody were fully booked—but a series of cancellations had happened.) Airline passengers, for instances, can wait for the either *the most recently available seat* or *the latest available seat*. Only in this *one* sense do those words mean the same thing. But, normally, the sentence in question means *the appointment as late as possible in the day.*

Comment: It is rather unclear what is being asked here: why would anybody think that *the latest* could mean the first? There is an ambiguity in *available today*: it can mean that the appointment would be **for** today, or merely that the appointment can be made today (possibly for some other day). Asking about that ambiguity would, however, be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

The latest appointment

Means, the appointment available at the latest possible time of the day. The last appointment available, before they close.

By contrast, the earliest appointment available, would be the first one available, counted from the time of asking. The next free slot, from now.

This is distinct from the meaning of 'latest' as 'the fashionable and new'. It doesn't mean that, here!

As in 'the latest dance'. Unless the type of appointment was new. 'I'd like the latest kind of appointment please - the kind with free coffee and biscuits!' But no, we are not talking about that. But that may be where the confusion is coming from. From whence the confusion emanates.

Definition of Latest:

1. The latest acceptable time (yes, this is what we are talking about!)
2. Current and popular (no, not this one!)

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latest